# H2o flow automl temporary sample frame

Tags: frame, h2o, temporary, automl

I have a large frame and used h2o flow run automl with a deep learning algo. However, the training metrics are calculated on a “temporary sample frame”. I could not find any info to this. I am not sure if the automl has been run on the full frame or just thus temp frame. Can someone help to understand or give a pointer? BTW, I don’t find this feature convenient.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where did you read that the metrics are calculated on a "temporary sample frame"?  That's not the case.  By default the leaderboard returns 5-fold CV metrics.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Erin! I have updated my original post with a screenshot. It happens when I click any of the models in the autoML process. If you take a look at the "frame" part and from the name, it downsampled my frame by 0.05%. The "description" part indicates that only 9993 samples wan used for the metrics. However in my original frame, I have tens of millions of records. Thanks for your help!

Comment: More information: I don't have the "automl_training_###_hex_temporary_sample.0.05%" frame. It should be created by H2O flow at some stage. I used versions 3.22.1.6 and 3.26.0.8 and saw this on both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case for Deep Learning models and is not the case for any other models produced by the AutoML process.  For efficiency reasons (and since H2O is designed for very large datasets), the training metrics in Deep Learning models are calculated on a subset of the original training frame.

There is a parameter in the [H2O Deep Learning algorithm](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/deep-learning.html) called `score_training_samples` that defaults to 10,000 rows (and since we do approximate sampling, also for efficiency reasons, it makes sense that the actual subset size is 9,993).

This should be a good approximation for training error.  The only way to change this in Flow would be to train a Deep Learning model manually (outside the AutoML process).

Comment: Thanks! It would be useful to let user to take control of it.

Comment: I don't know if this helps you, but it's possible to override algorithm parameters via the H2O AutoML Python API via a recently added hidden argument called `algo_parameters` (for reference). Example: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/97d757c3fee81a2bbc8c18d7821bfe15013c961f/h2o-py/tests/testdir_algos/automl/pyunit_automl_model_selection.py#L252

Comment: Definitely will try it. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @XWen Make sure to download the nightly release as this has not been in a stable release yet. http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/latest.html